# How to call change event on bootstrap date-picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a field on which i implement bootstrap date-picker. It is working correctly.But when i change the date its change event is not called. This is how i implement date picker.

Html :

```
 <label class="control-label">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" id="StateDatePicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

In javascipt:

```
      $StateDatePicker = $("#StateDatePicker");
        $(".date-picker").datetimepicker({


  format: "MM/DD/YYYY"
        })
```

This is how i called change event.

```
        $StateDatePicker.on("change", function () {
            //Performing functionality 
        });
```

It is not working. I have also implemented on change on simple text box. It works but date time change event is not working? Need help !

Comment: call like this n check  $StateDatePicker.change(function ()  {
            //Performing functionality 
        });

Comment: try this `$StateDatePicker.on('changeDate', function(ev){   alert('date is changed');});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
$("#StateDatePicker").on("dp.change", function(e) { alert(); });
```

I got same problem and I tried this..worked for me..`dp.change` Fired when the date is changed.

Comment: why? an explanation would be helpful

Comment: glad it could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use dp.change event not 'change' event.

```
$StateDatePicker.on("dp.change", function () {
     //Performing functionality 
});
```

Comment: You could review other events with following page. 

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/